# only display first 2 results using foreach

Tags: php

How can i make this foreach line only go through results 0 to 1 ?

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $forum_category) { ?>
```

I don't want to display all the results just the first 2 .

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanx

Justine Smithies

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
foreach (array_slice($categories, 0, 2) as $forum_category){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php $i = 0;
  foreach ($categories as $forum_category) { 
     if($i < 2) {
         // display result
     }
     $i++;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: @GeneSys no. Inside if it will display result.

Comment: @GeneSys Why would you want to break it? This means continue the foreach loop 'till the end but only do (whats inside the if condition) if $i is less than 2

Comment: Should be added though that if you don't want to do anything at all with the other `$categories` it's better to `break;`

Comment: Woops! You guys are damn right. Sorry for the confusion caused :) So if there was an `else` statement, this is where I'd put a `break` (as the `foreach` would iterate until the very end of `$forum_category`). Wouldn't you?

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach.

```
<?php

     $count = 0;
     foreach ($categories as $forum_category) {
           if($count == 2)
               break;
           else {
                     // Your Code
           }
        $count++;
     }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<?php for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){you can do anything with $categories[$i]}?>`

or you can add a parameter `$i=0` before your `foreach` statement and:

```
$i=0;
<?php foreach ($categories as $forum_category) { $i++; if($i>2) return }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep a counter.
Based on the limited structure you gave, all I can suggest is:

```
<?php 
    $categoryNumber = 0;
    foreach ($categories as $forum_category) { 
        $categoryNumber++;
        if($categoryNumber > 2){
            continue;
        }
        //...
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
    $categories[$i];
}
```

or

```
foreach ($categories as $forum_category) { 
   if($i < 2) {
       $categories[$i];
   }
   $i++;
}
```

or just

```
$categories[0];
$categories[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $i = 0;
  foreach ($categories as $forum_category) { 
     if($i <= 1) {
         //code
     }
     $i++;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: condition should be `$i <= 1`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($categories as $forum_category) {
    echo $forum_category;
    if($i == 1) break;
$i++;
}
```